# How can I set my upload path by date?

Tags: entries, assets

I have a directory structure in place that I'd like to mimic in Craft. File uploads are first categorised by Year, then by month so the directory sturcture is like such

```
-- 2014
---- 01
---- 02
---- 03
---- 04
---- 05
---- 06
```

I've tried this but it still only uploads to the root folder I setup in sources

```
/uploads/{postDate.format('Y')}/{postDate.format('M')}
```

Am I using the wrong syntax? Do I need to use now | date ('Y') instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you create an asset source `uploads`. Then you create an asset field and set its upload location subfolder to `{postDate|date('Y')}/{postDate|date('m')}`

When you edit an entry, any files you upload will go in the subfolder for the year and date. If you have selected **Restrict uploads to a single folder?** in the asset field, then only assets in that subfolder can be used.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I missed the **Restrict uploads to a single folder?**